# Breaking out of a Protractor .filter() or .map() loop

Tags: selenium, protractor, browser-automation, e2e-testing, webautomation

I'm using Protractor and cucumber framework; how do I break out of a .filter or .map loop? I do not want to continue to iterate further if I found a match!

```
Page.prototype.getElementByKey = function (key) {
      var foundElement = null;
      return someElement.all(by.css('.someClass')).map(function (rawItem, index) {
        var itemObject = new ItemObjectClass(rawItem);
        return itemObject.getItemKey().then(function (foundItemKey) {
          var matched = String(foundItemKey).trim() === String(key).trim();

         console.log(' Matched: { ' + matched + ' }  index {'+index+'}');
          //if we have a match break out of the .filter function
          if (matched) {
            foundElement = itemObject;
            throw new Error("Just our way of breaking out of .filter() above");
          }
        });
      }).then(function () {
        //callback
        throw new Error('\n!!!!!Callback should not be called; 
       this means that we could not find an element that matched the passed in key above');
      }, function (error) {
        //error
        console.log('\n*******************errorCallback was called; '+error);
        return foundElement;
      });
    };
```

The above code finds the element but continues to iterate until the end instead of stopping when there's a match and breaking out by calling the **errorCallback** function.

Given that .map function returns "***a promise that resolves to an array of values returned by the map function***" http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map, I'm taking advantage of the fact that a promise will call its errCallback if the promise cannot be resolved.

By throwing an a fake error, the ***errorCallback*** should be called and thereby break out of the .map loop.

Unfortunately, it successfully throws the error but continues with the loop instead of breaking out. I know that because when I

> console.log("boolean "+matched+" and index "+index);

I get this:

```
matched: false index: 0
matched: false index: 1
matched: true index 2 //it should have stopped here since matched = true
matched false index 3 // this should NOT have printed
```

so breaking out isn't working any ideas?

Comment: return (String(foundItemKey).trim() === String(key).trim()); should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning a single element, so `.reduce` would be preferable.

Here is a usage example to return the first link where the text is "mylink":

```
var link = element.all(by.css('a')).reduce(function (result, elem, index) {
    if(result) return result;

    return elem.getText().then(function(text){
        if(text === "mylink") return elem;
    });

}).then(function(result){
    if(!result) throw new Error("Element not found");
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Hey Florent, I tested your solution and it works; it breaks out as soon as there's a match and stops iterating over the other elements. Question: why does this work? I read the documentation on .reduce() and am still a bit confused. if(result) return result; this is where the magic happens right? Basically, as soon as that accumulator (result) is set, you're returning immediately thereby breaking out of the loop right? A similar set up with .filter() or .map() doesn't work so could you please explain why/how this works? Thanks again for this working solution

Comment: Lastly, how do I use the value returned by that function/method? For some reason, I'm able to break out correctly and return as soon as I find a match but I'm not able to use the returned value externally (outside of that function). I appreciate your help on this; if I figure it out before you respond, then I'll post it on here because I think knowing how to use the returned value would complement your answer nicely.

Comment: @pelican, the difference is that `map` and `filter` iterate each call while `reduce` chaines the calls and waits for the first call to be resolved to proceed to the second one. The method `reduce` returns a promise. So you can access it outside the function with `.then`, just like you would access the result from `.getText()`.

Comment: I know this method returns a promise which you can resolve with that **.then()** call but for some reason I'm not able to read its value externally; if you were to package the method above into a function named "getLink()" and did something like this: return getLink().then(function(resolvedLink){ console.log(resolvedLink);...}); you'd see that you don't get the link text but undefined.  getLink(0 actually belongs to a class file in my case; I'm just sudo coding for illustration here. Maybe it's something I'm doing wrong, not sure; will update this answer if I find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Florent, I finally figured out the issue; I wasn't returning the **result** from the callback; could you please update your answer above to return the **result**? This would help others that come upon this page. Thanks again so much Florent for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from your post is, you would like to exit loop(iterate) when find a match element.

*If yes*, then better go with ***.filter()*** method. As it iterates on all available list of element finders and returns when a match finds.

```
Code Snippet:

element.all(by.css('.items li')).filter(function(elem, index) {
          return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
                                if(text === 'RequiredElementFind'){
                                      return ele;//return matched element
                                 };
    });
}).click();//only matched element comes from the loop do what would you like    
  to do
```

Comment: Instead of the if() statement, you could have just returned "return text ==="RequiredElementFind"; but this solution will NOT exit on first match. It will filter the right elements TRUE; but it will continue to iterate over the other elements in the list until it's reached the bottom of the list then return an ElementArrayFinder that represents an array of elements that satisfy the filter function. You're still evaluating the rest of the elements eventhough you're only interested in the FIRST match or the first element that matches the filter condition. So this solution will NOT work but thank